# Uploading a large file with PHP loses other input values

Tags: php, forms, upload

I made a simple script that uploads file that are submitted through a simple html form,
It works fine with files that are smaller than 5 mega bytes.
When I upload larger files they start to screw things up..

I thought it might be that the execution time is too short, so I used this:
set_time_limit(500);

Sadly, it didn't make any difference.

In the form, I have a hidden input that helps me detect if the form was submitted
Next, I checked the apache error log and I found that that input was null,
So it seems like the long execution time loses the other values..

is there any simple solution for this? or shall I just change the way I detect if the form was submitted?

Thanks

Comment: Have you also changed the max file upload limit in the ini file

Comment: Seems to me it's a good idea to check hidden field, just in case you would check  if your file exists

Comment: @SudipPal I can't change that as I'm hosting my website on a shared web hosting service and they don't want to change too many things for me..

Comment: @sukinsan Yeah, I might actually add another operator to detect if the file exists, if it does i'll execute the script.. I'll make the change and update back here if it worked or not :)

Comment: @sukinsan Nope, I managed to detect if the form was submitted.. but the file seems to be lost after the upload is complete, I tried checking the type / name / size of it but it's all empty..

Comment: well, you can try to take field [tmp_name], if it's empty then file doesn't exist, form wasn't submit, if it's not empty use it with function file-exists("/home/www/happyfile.jpg"); here you would get true/false, true - form was submitted. Did you get me?

Comment: @sukinsan I'm passed checking if the form was submitted or not.. I'm trying to move the file to the appropriate folder afterwards but it's lost, it doesn't exist on the server.. what could cause that?

Comment: hmm, maybe you are trying to move file in the directory that doesn't exist, so you have to check path to the folder with is_dir("/dir/dir2") ; if it returns false you have to create it mkdir("/dir/dir2",true); and after you would move your file to that directory

Comment: @sukinsan Nah, it works fine with smaller files, the path is correct. I suppose it's because of the php Ini settings such as post_max_size and such, I'll contact my hosting provider and see if they can change that for me, thanks for your help though!

Comment: What do you get when you output `$_FILES['yourfile']['error']` ? also posting some of your code would help very much

Answer (score 0):

Please check you php settings in php.ini for maximum post size with post_max_size = ?